# Result of query is a resource URI

Tags: sparql

I am currently trying to learn how to query RDF data with SPARQL using resources on **DBPedia** and experimenting with the [Virtuoso SPARQL Query Editor](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) , but I seem to have misunderstood something.

For example, I am trying to find out the director name of Pulp Fiction, using this resource :
`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction`, so my (simple) query is:

```
SELECT ?dirName
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction>
WHERE 
{ 
     ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/director> ?dirName.
}
```

It works but the result is a URI resource : `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Quentin_Tarantino`.
Now i want to retrieve the birth name of the director, so i tried

```
SELECT ?dirRes ?dirName 
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction>
WHERE 
{ 
    ?s      <http://dbpedia.org/property/director>  ?dirRes. 
    ?dirRes <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?dirName.
}
```

without success, the result is an empty array...

Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FROM` part selects the database that you want to query, not the entity.

Remember that RDF consists of triples that have subject-predicate-object structure. You're looking for:

```
Pulp_Fiction director ?director
```

So let's query for that:

```
SELECT * {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction> <http://dbpedia.org/property/director> ?director.
}
```

Now to get properties of the `?director` resource, add more triples to the query:

```
SELECT * {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Pulp_Fiction> <http://dbpedia.org/property/director> ?director.
  ?director <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthdate.
}
```

You can make the query shorter by using predefined prefixes instead of the full `<...>` URIs. You can get a list by clicking “Namespace prefixes” in the top right corner. If you have the choice between using `dbpprop` and `dbpedia-owl`, always go with the latter because the classes and properties in that namespace are better managed. Result:

```
SELECT * {
  dbpedia:Pulp_Fiction dbpedia-owl:director ?director.
  ?director dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthdate.
}
```